# how do i pass variables to a layout in symfony?

Tags: symfony1

when i pass variables from a controller they are only passed to a template, not a layout surrounding that template.

how do i pass variables to a template?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [slots](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/04#chapter_04_slot_s).

In your action method:

```
$this->getResponse()->setSlot("foo", "12345");
```

In your layout template:

```
<?php echo get_slot("foo", "default value if slot doesn't exist"); ?>
```

which will output the slot contents.  In this example, you'll see `12345` appear in your layout.  If you don't set a slot's value in the action, you can supply a default value to be shown instead in the layout.

Comment: Thanks. Ran across this today. Seems like variables set in the action would be available in the layout. In my case, the variables $module and $action are available in the layout.

Comment: @yellottyellott I believe Symfony sets these itself, like it sets the `$sf_user` variable, although I may be wrong - it's been a while since I worked on a Symfony 1.x project.